# ¿Por que no sale por la consola la variable que quiero en PHP?

Tags: php, javascript

Saludos, tengo este código de JS donde usoAJAX ($("#pass") es la contraseña del formulario):

```
    function egiaztatuPasahitza(){
        var data = $("#pass");
        var request = $.ajax({
            url:'egiaztatuPasahitza.php',
            data: data,
            dataType:'html'
        });
        request.done(function(data){
            if(data == true) {
                alert("true");
             } else {
               alert("false");
            }
        });
        request.fail(function(data){

        });
    };
```

Que llama a este código PHP:

```
$pasahitzak = fopen('../DATUAK/toppasswords1.txt','r');
$pass = $_REQUEST[data];
while ($linea = fgets($archivo)) {
    $aux[] = $linea;    
    $numlinea++;
    echo "<script>console.log( 'Pasahitza: " . "$pass" . "' );</script>\n";
    if("$pass"=="$linea"){
        echo "<script>console.log( 'Pasahitza: " . "$pass" . "' );</script>\n";
        echo "true";
    }else{
        echo "false";
    }
}
fclose($pasahitzak);
```

Este código lee un fichero línea por línea para compararlo con una contraseña que viene de un formulario. 
Mí problema es que al hacer las líneas como esta:

```
echo "<script>console.log( 'Lerroa: " . "$linea" . "' );</script>";
```

La consola no lo lee y sale solo la información de la petición así (no hay nada más que el desplegable aunque lo cierre):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que no hay nada incorrecto en el código pero no sé porque no lo registra en la consola. He probado a cambiarlo por un alert() y tampoco lo hace.
Saludos.

Comment: Y si cambias la línea por algo así: echo "<script>console.log( 'Lerroa: " . $linea . "' );</script>"; no necesitas encerrar la variable en " "

Comment: eso lo sigues leyendo a través de un ajax? porque a través de ajax así nunca te va a funcionar

Comment: Sigue sin registrarlo...

Comment: La pregunta de @Sr1871 es muy válida, si es ajax no funciona así...

Comment: No, esto lo hago en PHP y lo leo de la variable que cojo del formulario de HTML

Comment: He editado la pregunta añadiendo el código de AJAX por si se me ha pasado algo o hay algo que esté mal. Yo no veo nada

Comment: Razón tiene @Sr1871 al afirmar que así no te va a funcionar, el console.log() lo debes hacer desde tu JS

Comment: No lo creo, he mirado en más de una web y es correcto usar el console.log() así en PHP. En todas las que he mirado ponía de ese modo.

Comment: Si es correcto pero no por vía ajax ya que todo lo que hagas en ese echo será una respuesta y no propiamente al servidor en el que corres.
Esto funciona si es que estás corriendo directamente ese archivo, pero si lo consumes vía ajax no

Comment: @MikelMolinuevo, coloca esta línea dentro de un DIV: `echo "<script>alert( 'Lerroa: " . "$linea" . "' );</script>";`

Comment: No entiendo, es PHP no HTML. Dices que cambie el contenido de un DIV?

Comment: Mikel aquí la cuestión interesante es lo que tú quieres hacer al final de esa comprobación. ¿Quieres saber las líneas del archivo que fueron `TRUE` y las que fueron `FALSE`? ¿Quieres saber quienes son esas personas, etc, etc, etc? ¿Quieres mostrar esa información al CLIENTE desde el cual se envió la petición AJAX?  Por lo general lo que se hace en el servidor (PHP)  es construir una respuesta organizado, por ejemplo en un JSON y enviarla de vuelta a Ajax... entonces en el `done` de Ajax muestras el resultado de lo que pasó en el servidor.

Comment: Quiero saber si alguna de todas ha sido true

Comment: @Sr1871 pon tu comentario como respuesta y lo marco como tal

Comment: O sea, si lo que quieres es comprobar que al menos una ha sido `TRUE`, puedes mejorar el rendimiento del programa... en cuanto encuentre un `TRUE` lo metes en un array, paras el bucle `while` (no tiene sentido seguir leyendo filas en este caso) y luego respondes con un JSON que leerás en el `done` de Ajax. No sé por qué quieres complicarte con procedimientos rebuscados, imprimiendo código JS en el código del servidor.

Comment: No son procedimientos complicados, es simplemente que soy nuevo con esto y hago lo que puedo. Mi intención al imprimirlo era ver si las variables del archivo realmente se leían bien. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La cuestión es como se menciono en comentarios así no funciona a través del ajax, ya que todo lo que hagas con echo es una respuesta al ajax

Contando tu anterior pregunta necesitas el true y demás valores, puedes probar con esto

```
$pasahitzak = fopen('../DATUAK/toppasswords1.txt','r');
$pass = $_REQUEST[data];
$response = ['valid' => 'false', 'pass' => NULL];
while ($linea = fgets($archivo)) {
    $aux[] = $linea;    
    $numlinea++;
    if($pass==$linea){    
        response['valid'] = "true";
        response['pass'] = $pass;
        break;
    }
}
fclose($pasahitzak);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Ahora en tu js puedes extar los valores en el done

```
request.done(function(data){
  if(data.valid == true) {
    alert("la contraseña correcta fue" + data.pass );
  } else {
     alert("false");
  }
});
```

Comment: Se puede mejorar el rendimiento del código, parando el bucle en cuanto encuentre uno `true`. Según lo dicho en comentarios, él quiere evaluar solamente si hay al menos uno que sea `true`. Cuando encuentre el primer `true` no tiene sentido leer las demás líneas del archivo. Se puede en ese momento cerrar el bucle y el archivo y enviar la respuesta a Ajax. Se ganaría mucho si el archivo tiene muchos miles o millones de líneas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, he añadido dicha validación

Comment: Faltaría un `break;` para que salga al encontrar el `true`. Algo así: `if($pass==$linea){    
        response['valid'] = "true";
        response['pass'] = $pass; break; //Saldrá del while al encontrar lo que se buscaba, un true
    }`

Comment: @A.Cedano si se pone el break; solo se saldría del if, para eso puse el !isset($response['pass]), ya que una vez que response['pass'] sea igualada a algún valor, este devolvera true y ya no entrará en el while por lo que rompe el ciclo principal.

Comment: No, `break` sale de los bucles, no de los condicionales. Si miras el Manual de PHP, ponen precisamente un ejemplo de salida de `while` con un `break` que está dentro de un `if...`

Comment: Tienes razón, pero switch no es un bucle y funciona, me fui con la finta la verdad, aun así el isset() en el while hubiera cortado el ciclo. De todas formas añado el break a la respuesta, gracias por la info